# CardLayout error: wrong parent for card layout

Tags: java, swing, illegalargumentexception, cardlayout

I have used cardlayout for one of my classes, however it is showing an error.

My code runs similar to this:

```
// panels instantiated
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
panel1.setLayout(cl);
panel2.setLayout(cl);

panel1.add(new JLabel("0 0"), "0");
panel1.add(new JLabel("0 1"), "1");

panel2.add(new JLabel("1 0"), "0");
panel2.add(new JLabel("1 1"), "1");

add(panel1);
add(panel2);

cl.show(panel1, "0");
cl.show(panel2, "0");  // error at this line
```

Why is it not considering panel2 as a parent container (IllegalArgumentException)?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CardLayout is not a layout that can be shared among containers and you should add the CardLayout to one container only. If you need two containers using the layout, give each its own CardLayout object.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the advice. But, why does it ask for a parent container in one of the parameters if it is intended to be used for 1 container per object?

Comment: @user2999870 Because the `CardLayout` doesn't actually maintain a reference to the container it's applied to, so in order to update the container, it needs a reference to it

Comment: @user2999870: what he said.

Comment: @user2999870 Also, the names you give each component could be duplicated among multiple containers, how would CardLayout resolve this?